# How to cast from static generic functions in java that don't take parameters?

Tags: java, generics, guava

In the project that i've been working on i user guava library.
I have something like this:

```
Optional< User > loginUser( ) {
    User user = storage.get( request.id );

    boolean success = ( user == null ) ? 
            false : user.password.equals( request.password );

    return success == true ? Optional.of( user ) :Optional.absent ( );
}
```

and compiler gives me the error:

Cannot cast from Optional< Object > to Optional< User >

More over here is work around that works:

```
Optional< User > empty = Optional.absent ( );
return success == true ? Optional.of( user ) : empty;
```

How can I escape from creating empty variable ?

Comment: (not using Guava, but I suppose:) `Optional.<User>absent()`

Comment: @qqilihq that's an answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6721089) with type inferencing in case of conditional operator. Java generics doesn't infer the types from the return type some how. The workaround is to give explicit type argument:

```
return success == true ? Optional.of( user ) :Optional.<User>absent ( );
```

Oh, and please get rid of `== true`. That is simply not required. Also, the other conditional operator:

```
 boolean success = ( user == null ) ? false 
                                    : user.password.equals( request.password );
```

can be replaced with:

```
boolean success = (user != null) && user.password.equals( request.password )
```

Answer (score 6):

Okay, seems my guess was right ;-) So to have it as an official answer here:

`Optional.<User>absent()`

Btw, for brevity's sake, you can reduce to:

`return success ? Optional.of( user ) :Optional.<User>absent ( );`